# PHP UndefinedFunctionException in simply OR comparison

Tags: php, exception

I am working on a custom web shop project. Currently I am experiencing a strange error when using one of my classes:

```
namespace Services\MyServices;

class MyAppService {

    protected function someMethod($transfer_id) {
        ...
        $hash1 = sha1($someValue1);
        $hash2 = sha1($someValue2);
        $hash3 = sha1($someValue3);

        // The following code is in line 144
        $checkHash = (($hash1 == $transfer_id) || ($hash2 == $transfer_id) || ($hash3 == $transfer_id));
        ...
    }
}
```

> Fatal Error: Call to undefined function Services\MyAppService\ ()
>
> Uncaught PHP Exception UndefinedFunctionException: "Attempted to call function " " from namespace "Services\MyAppService"." at /webspace/..../Services/MyAppService/MyAppService.php line 144

So line 144 is just a simple OR comparison, isn't it? What could be the problem here?

Comment: Is there an "exotic" whitespace character somewhere before a `(` that PHP is interpreting as a function name...? Check your source code with a hex editor and/or retype that line.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much! I would have never found this problem. I have no idea how I typed this character but now it is gone :-)